# Naive SCP module in Elixir

Tags: error-handling, elixir

I'm trying to do a simple implementation of a `scp` wrapper in Elixir.

The code is working as intended, but I got a feeling that the error conditions can be simplified. Besides error handling, I don't the best way to append the `-r` flag if the `source_path` is a directory with a `cond` keyword.

```
defmodule Scp do
  def scp(user, ip, source_path, destination_path, timeout \\ 30) do
    scp_flags = [
      "-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no",
      "-oConnectTimeout=#{timeout}",
      "-oPasswordAuthentication=no",
      source_path,
      "#{user}@#{ip}:#{destination_path}"
    ]

    scp_flags =
      case File.dir?(source_path) do
        true -> ["-r" | scp_flags]
        _ -> scp_flags
      end

    if File.exists?(source_path) do
      case System.cmd("scp", scp_flags, stderr_to_stdout: true) do
        {resp, 0} ->
          {:ok, resp, 0}

        {resp, exit_code} ->
          cond do
            String.contains?(resp, "Permission denied") ->
              {:error, :permdenied, exit_code}

            String.contains?(resp, "Connection timed out") ->
              {:error, :conntimeout, exit_code}

            true ->
              {:error, :errunkown, exit_code}
          end
      end
    else
      {:error, :enoent, -1}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used Elixir in my life until seeing this question, so my feedback is very limited and I probably shouldn't be putting an answer on here. However, there are a few ways it could be simplified:

- the module `lstat(path, opts \\ [])` reads information about a path, returns a `FileStat` struct which has a `type:` field which can be `type: :device | :directory | :regular | :other | :symlink`; this could be used to determine what the path is (and whether to use `-r`), and if there is an error it means that the path does not exist (thus adding in the error handling)
- in the case `{resp, exit_code} ->` instead of checking the error message contents via `String.contains?`, do the switching based on exit code and then return the appropriate error messages.
- in the case `{resp, exit_code} ->`, I'd add a few extra error-handlers for statuses (for example directory not found on destination, invalid credentials, etc.)
- for the inputs (user and ip address), a regex could be used to ensure sanity (the ip address looks like an ip, the username is not blank, etc.)
- the case `true -> {:error, :errunkown, exit_code}` could be replaced with `_ -> {:error, :errunkown, exit_code}` as `_` appears to be a fall through (I'm unsure about this)